# Parsing XML to CSV in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to write a Python script that parses an XML file and generates CSV files for each table in the XML. Each table should contain its attributes. Additionally, I want to create a CSV file that represents the relationships between these tables.

Here's my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

def extract_tables_and_attributes(xml_file):
    parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="windows-1252")
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file, parser=parser)
    root = tree.getroot()

    tables = root.findall(".//{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901}Class")
    
    table_data = []
    
    for table in tables:
        table_name = table.find("{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901}name").text
        attributes = table.findall(".//{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901}Property")

        table_attributes = []
        for attr in attributes:
            attr_name = attr.find("{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901}name").text
            attr_type = attr.find("{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901}type").text
            table_attributes.append([attr_name, attr_type])

        table_data.append((table_name, table_attributes))
    
    return table_data

def export_to_csv(table_data):
    for table_name, attributes in table_data:
        csv_file_name = f"{table_name}.csv"
        with open(csv_file_name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csv_writer.writerow(['Attribute Name', 'Attribute Type'])

            for attr_name, attr_type in attributes:
                csv_writer.writerow([attr_name, attr_type])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_file = r"Gemeentelijk Gegevensmodel XMI2.1.2.xml"
    table_data = extract_tables_and_attributes(xml_file)
    export_to_csv(table_data)
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ggm to csv.py", line 39, in <module>
    table_data = extract_tables_and_attributes(xml_file)
  File "ggm to csv.py", line 6, in extract_tables_and_attributes
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file, parser=parser)
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1203, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 571, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 71765, column 176
```

'm working with the following XML and there don't appear to be any issues regarding well-formed. It would be great if someone could help me resolve this issue.

https://github.com/Gemeente-Delft/Gemeentelijk-Gegevensmodel/blob/master/Gemeentelijk%20Gegevensmodel%20XMI2.1.2.xml

I tried to run the script with different exports from Enterprise Architect to xml (uml), with multiple version but I keep getting the same issue on the same line.

edit:

The desired outcome would look like this (a table ("PAND") of the type class with its attributes of the type property. (this is one table but i expect many csv's with each their own table):

> Attribute Name,Attribute Type Bruto inhoud pand,EAJava_N6 Datum begin
> geldigheid pand,EAJava_DATUM Datum einde geldigheid pand,EAJava_DATUM
> GeometriePunt,EAJava_GM_Point Hoogste bouwlaag pand,EAJava_N3
> Identificatie BGTPND,EAJava_NEN3610ID Ind planobject,EAJava_INDIC
> Indicatie geconstateerd pand,EAJava_INDIC Inwinning geometrie
> bovenaanzicht,EAJava_GM_Object Inwinning geometrie
> maaiveld,EAJava_GM_Object Laagste bouwlaag pand,EAJava_N3 Label
> nummeraanduidingreeks,EAJava_C74E1553_32AE_4fd8_9796_00C6E1C51A11 Lod1
> geometrie pand,EAJava_GM_Object Lod2 geometrie pand,EAJava_GM_Object
> Lod3 geometrie pand,EAJava_GM_Object Oorspronkelijk bouwjaar
> pand,EAJava_JAAR Oppervlakte pand,EAJava_N6 Pandgeometrie
> bovenaanzicht,EAJava_GM_Surface Pandgeometrie
> maaiveld,EAJava_GM_MultiSurface
> Pandidentificatie,EAJava_AB8B30D0_FD1F_4c44_9396_BB05389EA20B
> Pandstatus,EAJava_E2CC5DFC_C264_4c21_8E47_F551958E1C17 Relatieve
> hoogteligging pand,EAJava_N2 Status voortgang
> bouw,EAJava_8C49F097_6D95_4406_B3B7_58AC102B6FD2

Comment: Provide your sample xml file

Comment: I put the link to the github in my post (its a very large file). Or is it desirable that I upload the xml file here?

Comment: What are the properties (columns) you need to take into csv file from XML

Comment: I need tables of: xmi:type: = uml:Class (for example "PAND"). And i need the attributes inside these tables of: xmi:type = uml:Property (for example "Attributen van pand" in the "PAND" table.

Comment: I added the full expected csv output for the table PAND in the first post

Comment: I downloaded the XML, which according to the server (Github?) was encoded as UTF-8. I ran your code and got the exact error on the exact line. I looked at that line and saw an encoding error. I tried to re-encode the file as Windows-1252 and that shifted the parse error to another line, with another encoding error. I'm not clear on Mojibake, but I think your file has it (at least the one you shared on Github). You could try changing the encoding of the parser in your code to `utf-8` and see if that fixes it; you might need to get a "clean" file without any mis-encoding errors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using different encodings and it did not fix the issue. I also tried exporting a fresh xml from the qea file with Enterprise Architect, but also this did not fix the issue. Unfortunately I do not own the originals that are posted on gitlab. But if the problem resides there, I think I will have to contact the source.

Comment: In the "raw" file view on GitHub, you can see “verplichte” (on line 71765; https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gemeente-Delft/Gemeentelijk-Gegevensmodel/master/Gemeentelijk%20Gegevensmodel%20XMI2.1.2.xml). I suspect that the typographic quotation marks (`U+201D` and `U+201D`) mess things up. The XML file claims to be encoded in Windows-1252, but the characters are not available in that encoding.

Comment: Assuming the XML is well formed and usable please give an example of what's a table/cell etc. `uml:Class` it's a value and it's not qualified so this `//{http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901}Class` will not find elements.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the python doc to handle [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3.11/howto/unicode.html) with `errors="surrogateescape"`. I checked with `charset_normalizer` the encoding first. It seems the XML declaration is not correct:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from charset_normalizer import detect
import csv

filename = 'Gemeentelijk Gegevensmodel XMI2.1.2.xml'

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    xml = f.read()

result = detect(xml)
print(result)
for k, v in result.items():
    if k == "confidence":
        en_conf = v
        print(k, v)
    if k == "encoding":
        en_cod = v
        print(k, v)

if en_conf == 1.0:
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding=en_cod, errors="surrogateescape") as f:
        data = f.read()
        # remove wrong declaration
        data1 = data.replace("<?xml  version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252' ?>\n","")
   
    with open('NewXML_'+filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
        # add new declaration
        f.write("<?xml  version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n")
        f.write(data1)
        
     
tree = ET.parse('NewXML_'+filename)
root = tree.getroot()

ns = dict([node for _, node in ET.iterparse('NewXML_'+filename, events=['start-ns'])])
#print(ns)

table_data = []
packagedElements = root.findall('.//packagedElement[@xmi:type="uml:Class"]', ns)
print(len(packagedElements))
for elem in packagedElements:
    if elem.find(".//ownedAttribute") is not None and elem.find(".//ownedAttribute").get("name") is not None:
        name = elem.find(".//ownedAttribute").get("name")     
    if elem.find(".//type") is not None and elem.find(".//type").get("{http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1}idref") is not None:
        ty = elem.find(".//type").get("{http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1}idref")

    row = name, ty

    table_data.append(row)

print(table_data)
print(len(table_data))

with open("table.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8', newline="\n") as csv_file:
    c_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in table_data:
        c_writer.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
{'encoding': 'cp775', 'language': 'English', 'confidence': 1.0}
encoding cp775
confidence 1.0
742

[('contactsoort', 'EAJava_AN80'), ('aantal kamers', 'EAJava_int'), ('einddatum', 'EAJava_Date'), ('winkelformule', 'EAJava_AN80'), ('aantalFulletimeVrouwen', 'EAJava_int'), ('aantalkassa', 'EAJava_int'), ('aanvangAanwezigheid', 'EAJava_DateTime'), ('nummer', 'EAJava_int'), ('naam', 'EAJava_AN250'), ('aanstellingsdatum', 'EAJava_Date'), ('naam', 'EAJava_AN250'), ('naam', 'EAJava_AN250'), ('naam', 'EAJava_AN250'), ('naam', 'EAJava_AN250'), ('aanstellingsdatum', 'EAJava_Date'), ('besloten', 'EAJava_Boolean'), ... shorted ]

742
```

Comment: `recover=True` truncates the file to around 5MB from 18MB so a lot of content is lost

Comment: @LMC I have reworked my answer and no longer use lxml. Thanks for your valuable hint.

Comment: Interesting. I fixed the file with `sed -re 's/“|”/\&quot;/g' file.xml` replacing the offending quotes. The file was parseable as is after that.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your response, I will look into this!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to analyze the XML and see which lines (words) have any bytes over 127 (\x7F) ("high bits"):

```py
import csv

with (
    open("input.xml", "rb") as f_in,
    open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f_out,
):
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(["Line #", "Words w/high bits"])

    i, line = int, bytes
    for i, line in enumerate(f_in, start=1):
        line = line.replace(b"\x09", b"").replace(b"\x0a", b"")  # drop tabs and newlines
        words: list[bytes] = []
        for word in line.split(b" "):
            for x in word:
                if x > 127:
                    words.append(word)
                    break
        if words != []:
            writer.writerow([i, words])
```

I spotted an inconsistent encoding of the word "Plaatsoriëntatie" in these two lines:

```
Line #, Words w/high bits
...
  7638, "[b'name=""Plaatsori\xc3\xabntatie"">']"
  7641, "[b'xmi:idref=""EAJava_enum_Plaatsori\xc3_ntatie""/>']"
...
```

- The first line properly encodes "ë" as UTF-8 (`\xc3\xab`).
- The second line looks like it was properly UTF-8 encoded at one time, then `\xab` ("«" in ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252) looks to have been replaced with "_".

I have a hunch that the source has the malformed encodings (e.g., `\xc3_`) baked in; I'd love to learn the truth of it if you can get down to it. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have not been able to solve the issue yet, but I am working on a different way to achieve my desired result. I am doing this through an export of Enterprise Architect in which I don't export the entire model but only a subset of the part I need. 

When I export the entire model, I end up with the same error albeit on a different line, it's in the same entity.

When I learn more about the cause of the error in the XML, I will update.

Comment: @Taliesin, good luck!